# Laravel HasManyThrough with a distinct collection count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables:

```
meters:              data_readings                                  data_types

id   col1 ...        id   meter_id    data_type_id   value          id   type   
123  .... ...        456  123         1              13.4           1    typeA
                     457  123         2              25.9           2    typeB  
                     ....
                     1001 123         1              36.5
                     1002 123         2              17.5
```

In my meters class, I have a `HasManyThrough` relation like this:

```
public function sensors()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        DataType::class,
        DataReading::class,
        'meter_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'data_type_id'
    );
}
```

I now want to `withCount` the distinct sensors this meter has, but  doing a

```
Meter::where('id', 123)->withCount('sensors')->first();
```

returns a count for each time a data type appears in the readings table.

How do I count the `distinct data_types` for the meter using the relation and the `loadCount` method? Tried using `'distinct()` in the relation but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I did it manually like this;

```
$query->withCount([
    'sensors AS sensors_count' => function (Builder $query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT data_readings.data_type_id)'))
            ->withCasts(['sensors_count' => 'integer']);
    },
]);
```